# Show that the subspace $\{(x,y) \mid x \in \Bbb Q \iff y \in \Bbb Q\}$ of $\Bbb R^2$ is locally connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Show that the subspace $\{(x,y) \mid x \in \Bbb Q \iff y \in \Bbb Q\}$ of $\Bbb R^2$ is locally connected.

A space is locally connected iff the components of every open set are open. So let $x \in \{(x,y) \mid x \in \Bbb Q \iff y \in \Bbb Q\}$ and consider $C(x, U_x)=\bigcup\{S \mid x \in S \subset U_x \text{ $S$ connected} \}$ for $U_x$ open neighborhood of $x$.

I know that $\Bbb Q$ isn't connected, but how can I approach this problem? I cannot do anything with this component $C(x, U_x)...$

Answer (score 2):

Call the subspace $X$. Note that if $(x, y)\in \mathbb{Q}^2$ then $(x, y)\mapsto (x\pm t, y\pm t)$ is a path in $X$.

Now take some open ball $U$ of $(x, y)\in X$ (or a small "diamond" in the plane if you prefer). There is some $(z, t)\in U$ with rational coordinates. Considering the paths like above in $U$ obtained starting from the point $(z, t)$ we see that there is a dense path-connected subspace of this $U$. In particular, its closure (in $U$) is also connected. This proves that the neighbourhood is actually connected.

[image]

I hope this bad picture explains further what I mean. I chose the diamond for the better visualisation. The reddish lines are the paths, we continue to make them until we get a dense path-connected subspace of $U$.