# Is ($\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}) \cup (\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q})$ connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Does anyone know whether or not the set ($\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}) \cup (\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q})$ is connected with the sub space topology from $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard topology?

I think $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ are both totally disconnected, but I’m unsure whether or not their union is connected.

Comment: Proceed [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4362006/476484) to show it's connected.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for pointing out that post to me!